# Проблема с jdbc, запрос ничего не выдает

Tags: java, jdbc

Пишу программу, которая принимает сообщения через dde, далее заносит их в список, и при нажатии на элементы этого списка программа читает нужные участки  сообщения делает запрос в БД и выдает нужную информацию, этакий дешифратор. Но возникли проблемы с запросом, при попытке его распечатать, ничего не выводится, скриншоты прилагаю. Запрос печатается, только если содержимое where пустое. В чем может быть дело? Причем при работе программы в оффлайн режиме, т.е. читая сообщения из файла в таком же формате все рабтоает чудесно, может ли это быть из-за несостыковки jdbc и dde?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас в базе есть записи, у которых flight_id равен пробелу?

Comment: нет, таких записей нет, но у меня все записи начинаются с пробела в БД

Comment: Но выведенная вами в консоль `queryFlight` как раз ищет записи у которых `flight_id = ' '`. Раз таких в базе нет, то ничего и не выведется.

Comment: Можете добавить код в котором содержимое where пустое?

Comment: дело как раз в том, что если where пустой я могу сделать его sout, а если он не пустой его sout не делается и как запрос он тоже не работает, не пустой работает только запрос qwe3(queryMessage)

Comment: Roman, пробовал, тогда sout работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело было в том, что при получении сообщения, оно содержало служебные символы, а именно '\r', с ними я считывал ключи для обращения к БД, именно поэтому не работал мой запрос. Т.е. запрос выглядел следующим образом "select * from qwe where 'asd' = 'qwe\r';"